# Translate Italian to English

Tags: sql-server

I have just become DBA for a database that support call monitoring software attached to our PBX. The software was developed in Italy and all objects (Tables, Columns, Procedures, Views etc) are named with Italian names *e.g.* the **Chiamate** table holds the **Call** data.

Can anyone suggest how I can build up a table of translations - a simple two column Italian to English table that I can use to reference which columns,tables I should use to report from - until I get to learn Italian!!??

I had an idea that it may be possible to use an online translation service?

any ideas gratefully recieved.

Jonathan

Comment: While this may have been on topic at the time it was asked, new questions like this should be asked on our sister site [dba.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [good Italian-English online dictionary](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/).

You could also build a list of all table names, and let it run through [Microsoft's translator](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/), which accepts whole texts:

```
 select name from sysobjects where type = 'u' -- = user tables
```

You could do the same for column names joining syscolumns etc., for example this way:

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
from   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
order by TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Another additional tip: you could create SQL Views using the translated table and column names and work with the views.

*Buona fortuna!*

**Update**: in a comment to this answer, [Fatherjack](https://serverfault.com/users/3984/fatherjack) writes:

> I have [written] a small .net app
>   that reads in a text file (each line
>   is a table name . column name), passes
>   it to www.microsofttranslator.com and
>   writes out the response to a new text
>   file. using
>   **api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc**.
>
> HOW TO's found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx), examples
>   [here](http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/Translator/GettingStartedwithMicrosoftTranslator.aspx)

Comment: P.S.: I speak Italian. If the list is not too long, send it to me: stefan.plattner -- at -- gmail.com.

Comment: I'm ideally hoping for something that I can access programmatically, from TSQL, PS, VBS. That I can pass in the object names and get a translated response.

Or I get Italian evening classes booked and ask some very wierd questions in the first few lessons:
How do you say "Please can you tell me the way to the Area Code?"

Comment: about 100 tables, over 1712 columns ...

Comment: :-)) I updated my answer ("Ho modificato la mia risposta.")

Comment: +1 for creating views with translated column names.  Once I did this for an AS/400 application with 8 letter table and column names that used a coding scheme.

Comment: I was thinking that I would create views for the tables but have them in a different schema ie [dbo].[chiamate] would have a [english].[calls] view on based it ...

Comment: A few hours (may be 3) over the w/end and I have a small .net app that reads in a text file (each line is a table name . column name), passes it to www.microsofttranslator.com and writes out the response to a new text file.

' http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V1/SOAP.svc
HOW TO's found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287.aspx
Examples:
http://www.viawindowslive.com/Articles/Translator/GettingStartedwithMicrosoftTranslator.aspx

will blog details when I get chance

what I have learned about .Net makes time spent worthwhile and translation is close enough to use

Comment: Nice! I'll update my answer. So that other people with the same problem could learn from your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Get a good Italian to English dictionary and do it manually - the results from babelfish or a mechanical translation service will probably be slightly nonsensical and need manuan intervention anyway.

As an example, this real estate listing ...

> TRILOCALE IN PICCOLO CONDOMINIO CON
>   POCHE UNITA' ABITATIVE. L'APPARTAMENTO
>   è SITO AL PRIMO PIANO E SI COMPONE DI:
>   INGRESSO, CUCINA ABITABILE, SOGGIORNO,
>   2 CAMERE, SERVIZIO, 2 BALCONI E BOX.
>   LIBERO SUBITO, NON ARREDATO, ZONA
>   TRANQUILLA.

... gets translated by babelfish to:

> TRILOCALE IN LITTLE ONE CONDOMINIO
>   WITH LITTLE UNITA' INHABITED. L'
>   APARTMENT is SITUATED FIRST AL SLOWLY
>   AND IT IS MADE UP OF: INCOME,
>   HABITABLE KITCHEN, STAY, 2 ROOMS,
>   SERVICE, 2 BALCONIES AND BOX. FREE
>   QUICKLY, NOT FURNISHED, CALM ZONE.

Real estate listings are fairly idiomatic, but then so are database schemas.  To take the above example, unless you knew that an Ingresso was a porch, a Soggiorno was a lounge or a Cucina Abitabile was an open-plan kitchen you wouldn't get much sense from this translation.  Also, some of the jargon is idiomatic Italian - a Trilocale (roughly: three spaces) is a two-bedroom apartment.  The living area and bedrooms figure in the count of rooms but bathrooms and suchlike do not.  Mechanical translators are typically going to do poorly unless they are aware of these idiomatic rules.

A database schema will have highly idiomatic wordings in it, and possibly lots of abbreviations.  SAP R/3 is famous for its cryptic database schema where the table names and field names are based on abbreviations of German words.  It is difficult to understand if you are not a fluent German speaker (and not necessarily that easy if you are).  Mechanical translation is unlikely to help much with this.

You will find that Italian has many root words in common with English and with a little tourist-level working knowledge of the language it is not hard to work out what a written passage means.  If the tables have a lot of abbreviated words making up the column names you may still have trouble.  I would consider taking up [splattne's](https://serverfault.com/users/45/splattne) offer to help with the transalation if you run into this type of problem.

Comment: Actually modern translation services are quite good. Sure, they can't reach a good human translator, but IMHO it's okay for translating single words. But don't try to translate Dante Alighieri. ;-)

Comment: Or Manzoni - My ragazza's bridge partner used to live in Lecco (not that I've ever attempted to read I Promessi Sposi ;-)

Comment: ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells - no way am I going to spend my time typing each object name into a form and then typing the translation into a select statement. My time as a DBA is more precious than that, despite no-doubt learning a good deal of Italian in the process!! ;)

Currently I am waiting for the firewall setting to be changed (oddly the site is blocked at the moment! :-/ ) so that I can at least review the microsoft translator link that splattne mentioned.

I realise that I wont get exact translations but I think I can get close enough on most to make it worthwhile

Comment: I meant a bound paper dictionary - the point is that a mechanical translator is quite likely to produce large quantities of deceptive or unhelpful results.  My gut instinct is that you won't get away without having to think about this.

Comment: You're also quite likely to find many columns with names that translate to something like foo_code, foo_id, foo_description or foo_amount.

Comment: just for kicks I tried the passage you gave in the microsoft translator:
THREE-ROOMED APARTMENT IN SMALL CONDOMINIUM WITH A FEW UNITS OF HOUSING. The APPARTAMENTO is site to the first floor and SI COMPONE of: entry, kitchen ABITABILE, stay, 2 rooms, service, 2 BALCONIES and BOX. NOW, NOT FURNISHED, FREE QUIET
I agree, certainly not english!

The database (and only I would know this as I didnt give that level of detail) is reasonably named - table and column names seem to be two word concatenated but CamelCase. The output is about 80% good and that is OK for my needs.
Thanks 4 ur comments

Answer (score 0):

Translating between languages is highly dependent on context.  As a simultaneous interpreter, my first question on a job is, "Di che cosa si tratta?" "What is this about?"  So, the "meaning of a (a word in a) column would depend on (the word in) column preceding it, and possibly following it.  Google translate takes this into account to some degree (the sliding window approach).  Since here the context seems somewhat restricted, recursion may be simpler.  The lookup should include as much "common information", context, as possible.  That information might be obtained by passing some of the free-text through some classifier program.